# WHERE clause match or null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have searched and searched and tested and tested but I can't seem to find the answer.

Here's the setup. I have 4 parameters coming in that can either:

1. Match a column in the table
2. Parameter and table column are null
3. There's no match for the parameter but the associated table column has a null

I've tried:

- PCN = ( CASE WHEN PCN = @group THEN @PCN
  WHEN PCN IS NULL THEN NULL
  END )

  1. Handles, 2. Doesn't Handle, 3. Doesn't handle
- ( PCN= @PCN
  or
  PCN is null )

  1. Doesn't handle, 2. Doesn't handle 3. doesn't handle
- (IsNull(PCN,'none') = IsNull(@PCN,'none'))

  1. Handles, 2. Handles, 3. Doesn't handle

Since the last one is the only one that's handling scenario 3, here's more details on that one.

```
DECLARE @bin varchar(6) = '123456'
   , @PCN varchar(50) = 'abc'
   , @Group varchar(50) = '0.0'
   , @NDC = '01234567891'
        
select * from dbo.Insurance
WHERE (IsNull([Group],'none') = IsNull(@group,'none'))
       and (IsNull(PCN,'none') = IsNull(@PCN,'none'))
       and (IsNull(BIN,'none') = IsNull(@bin,'none'))
       and (IsNull(NDC,'none') = IsNull(@NDC,'none') )
order by [Group] desc, PCN desc, BIN desc, NDC;
```

This query returns no results. My expectation is to return the row where Bin, Group and NDC match and PCN is NULL. Any insight you can provide would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

| RowId | BIN | PCN | Group | NDC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | abc | 0.0 | 01234567891 |
| 2 | 123456 | NULL | 0.0 | 01234567891 |

- Scenario 1 - PCN column = PCN variable , rowID 1 should be returned
- Scenario 2 - PCN column & PCN variable are null, rowID 2 should be returned
- Scenario 3 - PCN variable = 123, rowID 2 should be returned

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in text

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think you want `([Group] = @Group OR [Group] IS NULL)` and similarly for the other criteria.

Comment: @DanGuzman that's how it was originally - it doesn't work for the first or second scenario. It returns too many rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not the DBA nor in charge of making those kind of decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
((Group IS NULL AND @group IS NULL) OR (Group IS NOT NULL AND @group IS NOT NULL AND Group = @group ))
and ...
```

Solution 2:

```
(Group= @group) OR (ISNULL(Group, @group) IS NULL)
and ...
```

Comment: These solutions don't cover the third scenario, there's no match for the parameter but the associated table column has a null. See the updated question for additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

you can have 3 OR's per parameter

```
select      *
from        dbo.Insurance
where       ([Group] is null or @Group is null or   [Group] = @Group)
and         (PCN is null or @PCN is null or PCN = @PCN)
and         (BIN is null or @bin is null or BIN = @bin)
and         (NDC is null or @NDC is null or NDC = @NDC)
order by    [Group] desc
            , PCN desc
            , BIN desc
            , NDC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE 
    (colA = @a OR colA IS NULL)
```

1. The values match: accepts based on `colA = @a`
2. Both are NULL: accepts based on `colA IS NULL`
3. `colA` is NULL: also accepts based on `colA IS NULL`

But we also need to make sure no other cases pass:

4. There are values in both and they do not match: will not be accepted based on either half.
5. `colA` is not NULL and `@a` is NULL: also does not pass

Answer (score 0):

I discussed the business requirements with our team again. Slight adjustment and just in case anyone runs into something similar in the future, here were are the final requirements and solve:

1. Parameter and column are the same
2. Parameter and column are both null
3. Column has a wildcard (*)

> ```
> DECLARE @bin varchar(6) = '123456'
>  , @PCN varchar(50) = 'abc'
>    , @Group varchar(50) = '0.0'
>    , @NDC = '01234567891'
>         
> select * from dbo.Insurance
> WHERE ((IsNull([Group],'none') = IsNull(@group,'none')) OR [Group] = '*')
>      and
>      ((IsNull(PCN,'none') = IsNull(@PCN,'none')) OR PCN = '*')
>      and 
>      ((IsNull(BIN,'none') = IsNull(@bin,'none')) OR BIN = '*')
>      and
>      ((IsNull(NDC9,'none') = IsNull(@NDC9,'none') ) OR NDC9 = '*')
> order by [Group] desc, PCN desc, BIN desc, NDC;
> ```

Thank you everyone for your comments!